# Uploaded Data from Csv file issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, csv, visual-studio-2015

I have a problem with the data uploaded into my database from csv file. In my csv file, i have 8 rows which is 8 medicines. But when i upload the file, i have duplicates and also some medicine which are not in the file at all. Also, I have a lot of empty rows.

This is my code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < AllFiles.Length; i++)
{
    try
    {
        File_Name = AllFiles[i].Name;
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(string.Format(CSV_CONNECTIONSTRING, csvPath)))
        {
            using (OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [" + File_Name + "]", con))
            {
                da.Fill(dt);
            }
        }
        using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(ConString))
        {
            bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(0, "medicine_id");
            bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(1, "category_id");
            bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(2, "subcategory_id");
            bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(3, "med_name");
            bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(4, "brand");
            bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(5, "form_id");
            bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(6, "poison_schedule");
            bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(7, "strength");
            bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(8, "image");
            bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(9, "quantity");
            bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(10, "unit");
            bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(11, "threshold");
            bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(12, "price");
            bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(13, "manufacturer");
            bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(14, "special_instructions");

            bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "medicine";
            bulkCopy.BatchSize = dt.Rows.Count;
            bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dt);
            bulkCopy.Close();
        }

    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

The medicine_id does not match the one in the file but the rest of the information matched. I think it might be because it's going on in a loop, so it keeps reading the file till it reached the max number of rows, that's why i have duplicates, many empty rows and medicines which are not in the file. However, I'm not sure how to solve it.

Please help :(

Comment: That seems to me some discordance of format, the OLEDB expects the file to be encoded in some way that the file isn't. CSV is a pain in the ass as it can be sepparated by comma, by tabulation, fields can or cannot be quoted and so on. Check the content format and the expected one by OLEDB.

Comment: What driver are you using? Is this a case where the data within a column could be interpreted differently from record to record? ie "1/1/2015" string vs "1/1/15" date? [JetDriver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/guide/appendixes/microsoft-ole-db-provider-for-microsoft-jet) / Ace driver "replaced" the Jet driver, but documentation is nowhere to be found. Most of the Jet documentation, that I used so far, works in the ACE realm. If your columns are data that can swing more than 1 type, you can use a schema file to ensure data integrity.